# IDIVQ instruction works odd . . . 16 mod 100 = 0?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I want to check modulo value of dividing 1~1000 with 100 with assembly language x86-64.

The thing is that 'IDIVQ' instruction works odd and I don't understand why.

Here's my code

```
.L0:
  ##dividend in %rax
  ##divider in %rsi
  ##modulo in %rdx

  pushq   %rax      # store dividend
  movq  $0x00, %rdx # initialize %rdx
  idivq   %rsi      # divide %rax by %rsi , modulo in  %rdx
  cmpq  $0x00, %rdx # if divided
  je   .L1


.L1:
  popq %rax   # retrieve dividend
  inc  %rax   # increment
  'When dividend == 1000, return'
  jmp  .L0
```

On GDB it's like

```
(gdb) p $rax
$7 = 16
(gdb) p $rsi
$8 = 100
(gdb) step
77    idivq   %rsi        # divide %rax by %rsi , modulo in  %rdx
(gdb) step
78    cmpq  $0x00, %rdx # if divided
(gdb) p $rsi
$9 = 100
(gdb) p/x $rax
$11 = 0x28f5c28f5c28f5c
(gdb) p $rdx
$12 = 0
```

Anybody give me a hint why this is happening?

For now, I know that initializing %rdx matters.
when I do

```
movq $0x01, %rdx
idivq %rsi
```

The result changes, but totally incorrect like they are all 1 away from correct answer

when I put

```
movq $0x1000, %rdx
idivq %rsi
```

leads to segmentation fault.

Comment: Use `x/3i $rip` or similar to make sure you are looking at the correct code. Use `stepi` not `step` to make sure you are single stepping instructions.

Comment: Thank you for your  advice! but it doesn't actually make differences..

Comment: What's the point of that `cmpq` and `je`? The way your code is written you'll end up at `.L1` no matter what.

Comment: *leads to segmentation fault.*  No, that should lead to SIGFPE, an arithmetic exception fault.  (From the x86 `#DE` divide error hardware exception.)  Anyway, as Jester's answer shows, this question is not a [mcve] of your problem.  It's probably a duplicate of [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38416593) and [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36464879)

Answer (score 2):

You are not running the code you are showing or your cpu is broken (unlikely).

```
7     idivq   %rsi      # divide %rax by %rsi , modulo in  %rdx
(gdb) p $rax
$1 = 16
(gdb) p $rsi
$2 = 100
(gdb) si
8     cmpq  $0x00, %rdx # if divided
(gdb) p $rax
$3 = 0
(gdb) p $rdx
$4 = 16
```

Yes, you need to zero `rdx` because that's the top 64 bits of the dividend.

Comment: oh I think I got the hint! Thanks!

Comment: To use `-16` as dividend you need to sign extend it into `rdx` otherwise it will be interpreted as a big positive number. If you do that you get `rax=0` and `rdx=-16` as output.

Comment: @YewonLi: specifically, use `cdq` or `cqo` before `idiv`, zero EDX / RDX before `div`.